# Google Forms Complex Email Send on Form Submit with Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have this right now as a script to send an email to myself as a test showing that there is a new application submitted, but I am looking to have a full-fledged email sent to our HR department giving the name of every field following by a : and a space then what their answer was. I know you can do this and have found a script that I tried to get to work, but it kept failing and the developer was no help in trying to help me fix it. I really would love to get this done for my HR department so that we can move on from creating a new application. Here is my code so far, I removed my email for privacy issues:

```
function sendFormByEmail(e){
  var email = "emailgoeshere";
  var subject = "A New Employment Application has been Submitted"; 
  var message = "A New Application Has Been Submited. Please go to the spreadsheet for more details.";
  MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message);
}
```

Thanks again!

Comment: You could at least tell how many data columns you'd like to send and if the column headers can be used as field names. Knowing that I guess some people here could provide something for you to start with or some working example. (or even better, share a copy of the form without any personal or sensitive data)

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0AumkYYtzdXSTdGxJZkktQTgxcW9MeXp6UzRhaWI4ZVE&output=html

Comment: wow! that will be a long email ;-) but the code should be shorter since it's a repetition of a single process. I guess an html table would be nice looking but plain text is maybe more appropriate for you ?

Comment: plain text would be great. i just need something that can easily be put into anything by a copy and paste simply.

Comment: It is giving me this error:
Invalid email: email (line 7)

Comment: I got it working, but the email is very messy:
A New Application Has Been Submited. Please find the details below :
Hired (Yes, No, In Process) : Hired (Yes, No, In Process) Reason : Reason Timestamp : Timestamp Last Name : Last Name First Name : First Name Middle Name : Middle Name Social Security Number (SSN) : Social Security Number (SSN) Driver's License Number : Driver's License Number Telephone Number : Telephone Number Cell Phone Number : Cell Phone Number Address : Address City : City State : State Zip Code : Zip Code Email Address : Email Address

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Or you could try this very simple one :**(read carefully comments in the script)**

```
function sendFormByEmail(){
var email = "email adress comes here";
var subject = "A New Employment Application has been Submitted";
var message = "A New Application Has Been Submited. Please find the details below :";
var row = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getLastRow();// assuming data is on the last row of the spreadsheet
var messagebody=createmessage(row);
MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message+messagebody);
}
//
function createmessage(row){
   var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var lastCol = ss.getLastColumn();
   var LF=  "\r\n"
   var body = LF
   var headers = sh.getRange(1,1,1,lastCol).getValues();
   var data = sh.getRange(row,1,1,lastCol).getValues();
   for(nn=0;nn<headers[0].length;++nn){
     body+=headers[0][nn]+" : "+data[0][nn]+LF
     }
Logger.log(body)
return body
}
//
//eof
```

As mentionned, data coming from the form must be on last row of data in the sheet and there must be some data to check how it works otherwhise answers=questions.

Comment: the spacing is messed up with a few things also. I could forward you the email if you'd like to look at it.

Comment: I got it now! Thank you! But, if this is done on form submit, will the newest row already be implemented?

Comment: yes... but the only issue is when 2 or more forms arrive exactly together... this case should be handled differently if it happens. There are posts on this in the ['old' google forum](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!categories/apps-script)

Comment: please consider marking this post as answered by choosing an answer ;-)

Comment: I swear I was going mad, for some reason the event based (functions with e parameter) weren't working, but this did. Thank goodness!

Answer (score 0):

I've developed a script that might help you, it's called FormEmailer. You can find it in the Script Gallery or grab the code on its [site](http://sites.google.com/site/formemailer).